# inline form validation error is collapse css alignments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii

This is yii framework code for inline form. when error ms.g display alignment is collapsed ...how can i solve it

**Framework Code**

```
<?php
            CHtml::$requiredCss = '';

            CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel = '<span class="text-red">*</span>';
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'clients-form',
                // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
                // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
                // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
                // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'errorMessageCssClass' => 'has-error',
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-inline',
                ),));
            ?>
            <div class="form body bg-gray">
                <?php // echo $form->errorSummary($model);  ?>


                <!--<p class="note">Fields with <span class="text-danger">*</span> are required.</p>-->
                <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'firstname', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'firstname', array("class" => "form-control ")); ?></div>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'firstname', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'lastname', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'lastname', array("class" => "form-control")); ?></div>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'lastname', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'username', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <?php echo ($model->isNewRecord) ? ($form->textField($model, 'username', array('size' => 47, 'maxlength' => 40, "class" => "form-control"))) : ($form->textField($model, 'username', array("readOnly" => "readOnly"))); ?>
                   <?php echo $form->error($model, 'username', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'dob', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'dob', array("class" => "form-control")); ?></div>
                   <?php echo $form->error($model, 'dob', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'emailid'); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'emailid', array("class" => "form-control")); ?></div>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'emailid', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'hashed_password', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'hashed_password', array("class" => "form-control")); ?></div>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'hashed_password', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'password', array('class' => "span2")); ?>
                    <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'password', array("class" => "form-control")); ?></div>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'password', array('class' => "errorMessage")); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="  footer">
                <center><?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('class' => "btn btn-success form-control")); ?></center>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-box1 {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 90px auto 0 auto;
}
.form-box1 .header {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background: #3d9970;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-box1 .body,
.form-box1 .footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
.form-box1 .body > .form-group,
.form-box1 .footer > .form-group {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.form-box1 .body > .form-group > input,
.form-box1 .footer > .form-group > input {
  border: #fff;
}
.form-box1 .body > .btn,
.form-box1 .footer > .btn {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-box1 .footer {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Make a demo maybe? This is a HTML/CSS issue, so post HTML/CSS, not PHP. Post rendered output, not php contents.